# How to trigger a pop up window from another pop up window in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, uikit

I want to open a popup from another popup and I used the below code, but when I click the pop up it moves to a new page instead of showing another popup. is there a way to create a popup effect with navigationController?

```
[weakself.navigationController pushViewController:deleteVC animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of pushing the view controller to the navigation stack, use `presentViewController:animated:completion:` method to open it modally.

It's important that you send this message to the presenting view controller itself, not to the navigation controller:

```objectivec
[weakself presentViewController:deleteVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```